# How to authenticate user using facebook native app during login with facebook JS SDK

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

Our website is using Login with facebook feature and working fine for desktop and mobile browser.The requirement is , on a mobile device if facebook app is installed then authenticate using facebook app rather than mobile browser

FB Community [question link.](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=2053391384896381&rdrhc)

Answer (score 0):

I think for doing this you will have to use facebook sdk for android so that you can use the native facebook authentication form
This link may be useful :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Our Website runs on mobile browser and its platform independent i.e  we need to open the native facebook app when a user clicks on sign-in-with-facebook button on mobile browser and authenticate itself from native app rather then using browser tab.